# neo4j database consistency errors

Tags: neo4j

some time ago we had some hosting provider storage issues, and (not sure if this is realted to our problem) now we have some consisteny problems within database. Starting clean slave with empty graph.db folder, does NOT result in slave geting full copy od data from the master.

Also, when doing backups, we get consistency check errors all the time:

```
Full consistency check
....................  10%
....................  20%
....................  30%
....................  40%
....................  50%
....................  60%
....................  70%
....................  80%
...........2013-08-28 08:50:28.184+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: The next block is not in use.
        DynamicRecord[2987807,used=true,light=false(120),type=0,data=byte[size=120],next=2987808]
        Inconsistent with: DynamicRecord[2987808,used=false,light=false(105),type=0,data=byte[size=105],next=-1]
.........  90%
...................2013-08-28 08:50:29.653+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: WARNING: The name is empty.
        PropertyIndexRecord[2035,in use,nameId=2036,propCount=0]
        Inconsistent with: DynamicRecord[2036,used=true,light=false(0),type=0,data=byte[],next=-1]
2013-08-28 08:50:29.657+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: WARNING: The block is empty.
        DynamicRecord[2036,used=true,light=false(0),type=0,data=byte[],next=-1]
. 100%
2013-08-28 08:50:29.658+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Inconsistencies found: ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
        Number of errors: 1
        Number of warnings: 2
        Number of inconsistent STRING_PROPERTY records: 1
```

I could not find/google any way to resolve this issue, no "mysqlcheck" alternative, or "repair table" tool, nothing...

Any help/tip would be greatly appriciated...

Thanks,
Andrija

Answer (score 4):

Neo4j doesn't provide any way to do this. Your best option may be to load in an older backup if possible.

The problem is that if you delete these corrupt records, neo4j is going to have a consistency checker for some of the logic(such as deleting a relationship is going to look for the next relationship to link with the previous), so you won't be able to remove them through the normal API.

Neo4j might be able to provide some verifier that can purge these bad records, but is that something that people would want? These records for the most part aren't able to be recovered as most of these are some type of linked list entries in Neo4j and once you've lost the reference you don't know which list it belonged to.

Comment: Four years have passed and nothing has happened.